# Toggle between enable/disable button doesnt work

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning reactjs and this is my very first code. Onclick the input fields will be disabled, however, when I click on enable the fields are still disabled. How can I fix this?

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import '../css/formContact.css';


export function Contact(){

    const [isDisabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

    function handleDisabling(){
        setDisabled({isDisabled : true})
    }

    function handleEnabling(){
        setDisabled({isDisabled : false})
    }

    return(
        <div id = 'contact'>
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <div className = 'form-contact'>
                <span>Name: <input type = 'text' disabled={isDisabled}/></span>
                <span>Surname: <input type = 'text'disabled={isDisabled}/></span>
                <span>Address: <input type = 'text'disabled={isDisabled}/></span>
                <span>G.P.A.: <input type = 'text'disabled={isDisabled}/></span>
                { isDisabled 
                    ? <button className = 'btn-add-date' onClick={() => handleEnabling()}>Enable</button>
                    : <button className = 'btn-add-date' onClick={() => handleDisabling()}>Disable</button>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Problem solved:

```
  function handleEnabling(){
        setDisabled(false)
    }
```

Comment: Does the disable work for the Name field?

Comment: On `handleDisabling()` and `handleEnabling()` the code should be something like: `setDisabled(true)` not `setDisabled({isDisabled : true})`

Answer (score 0):

setDisabled(true) instead of setDisable({ isDisabled : true }) will work

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong arguments to the state updating function (in your case setDisabled(...)). Unlike in class components, You don't have to pass the new value as an object. Just pass the value as it is. in your case you have to use

```
function handleDisabling() {
  setDisabled(true);
}

function handleEnabling() {
  setDisabled(false);
}
```

here is a working version of your code [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-swirles-699mm)